# Differential Backups - How old is too old for the most recent full backup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm migrating my application from one place to another, and the full is around 80 GB and difficult to move. It's is currently about 2 weeks old, and the differentials aren't growing in size too much so that's not a concern.

Are there any other concerns to be aware of using a 3-4 week old full backup and restoring the most recent differential?

Comment: you can create backup file of your old DB and restore on new DB make sure SQL version should be same of new DB OR current+

Comment: You could also backup your Full into several smaller files that are easier to move.  See my [blog post here](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/striped-backups-in-sql-server/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to be concerned with is that you need to restore all the log files after the latest differential. The amount of time elapsed between the full and the differential doesn't matter.

Comment: I'll take the differential when the system isn't in use, so I won't have to use log files. I was just concerned with the original full backup becoming stale or something along those lines....or encountering an increased risk of error during the restore because of the age of the full.

Comment: If you're moving the database, you should still take a tail log backup and restore it at the new destination.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found by first determining the maximum acceptable time it takes to perform a full restore, which is a business decision.

Once that is determined, given that the full restore takes a more-or-less constant (but slowly increasing) time, work out the maximum number of incremental backups you can afford to perform after the full restore.

Expressed mathematically:

```
Given:
  m = max allowable time to complete restoration after failure
  r = time it takes to restore full backup
  i = time it takes to apply an incremental backup
  n = the maximum number of incremental backups between full backups
Then:
  n = (m - r) / i
```